# Removing All Child Views from View

Tags: android

How would I remove all child views from a widget? For example, I have a GridView and I dynamically inflate many other LinearLayouts into it; later in my application I am looking to start fresh with that GridView and clear all of its child Views. How would I do this? TIA.

Answer (score 230, accepted):

```
viewGroup.removeAllViews()
```

works for any viewGroup. in your case it is GridView.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeAllViews()

Comment: Actually removeAllViews() throws an exception when called on GridView.  From the Docs: "This method is not supported and throws an UnsupportedOperationException when called."

Comment: That comment applies to the abstract base class from which ViewGroup is derived.   ViewGroup itself and all its derived classes do support removeAllViews.

Comment: How to get `ViewGroup` ?

Comment: @NimmagaddaGowtham most XxxLayout classes (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc.) are child classes of ViewGroup.  If you have one of those, you already have a ViewGroup.

Answer (score 16):

You can remove only some types of view in a **ViewGroup** with this function :

```
private void clearImageView(ViewGroup v) {
    boolean doBreak = false;
    while (!doBreak) {
        int childCount = v.getChildCount();
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<childCount; i++) {
            View currentChild = v.getChildAt(i);
            // Change ImageView with your desired type view
            if (currentChild instanceof ImageView) {
                v.removeView(currentChild);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (i == childCount) {
            doBreak = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Down-voted because the OP did not ask how to remove different types of child views. The OP wanted to remove all child views.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
RelativeLayout  relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.realtive_layout_root);
    relativeLayout.removeAllViews();
```

This code is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Try  this**

```
void removeAllChildViews(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            if (child instanceof AdapterView) {
                viewGroup.removeView(child);
                return;
            }
            removeAllChildViews(((ViewGroup) child));
        } else {
            viewGroup.removeView(child);
        }
    }
}
```